# Incorrect link to printing manager for android

Tags: android, printing

This is my first question ever, I apologize in advance for any mistake!

I'm trying to tie a printing function to my app. To do so, I use the code found there:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial

I implemented the printDocumentAdapter in a dedicated class, and I call the printing function by a button which depends on my main activity.

I cannot understand the error provided by the logcat when debug reaches line "printManager.print(jobName, printDoc, null);".
The button seems to work ok (all is well without the incriminated line).

Thank you very very much in advance for any help.

```js
public class SQLiteExampleActivity extends ListActivity {
 
 //private String[] intituleObservations;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "1er Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
        // Erased stuff here
      
    }
    
 public void printDocument(View view)
 {
  
  // Get a PrintManager instance
     PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

     // Give the job a name.
     String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + 
                        " Document";

     // Start a print job, passing a printDocumentAdapter as 
     //argument to handle the generation of a print document
     MyPrintDocumentAdapter printDoc = new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(this);
     printManager.print(jobName, printDoc, null);
 }



   
}
```

```js
package com.example.essaib;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.print.PageRange;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.print.PrintDocumentInfo;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument.PageInfo;
import android.print.pdf.PrintedPdfDocument;

import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;


public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
 Context context;
 private int pageHeight;
 private int pageWidth;
 public PdfDocument myPdfDocument; 
 public int totalpages = 4; // Défaut, à rendre dynamique
 
 public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Context context)
 {
  this.context = context;
 }
 
 /**
  * Layout method. 
  */
 @Override
 public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
                  PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                  CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                  LayoutResultCallback callback,
                  Bundle metadata) {
  
  // Creates a new PDFdocument with the right attributes
  myPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);
     
  pageHeight = 
                 newAttributes.getMediaSize().getHeightMils()/1000 * 72;
  pageWidth = 
                 newAttributes.getMediaSize().getWidthMils()/1000 * 72;
       
  // Responds to Cancellation request
  if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled() ) {
   callback.onLayoutCancelled();
   return;
  }
       
  // Returns print information to printing framework
  if (totalpages > 0) {
     PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
     .Builder("print_output.pdf") 
     .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
     .setPageCount(totalpages);
                   
     PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
     callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
  } else {
     callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
  }
 }
 
 /*
  * Called by the printing framework
  * 
  */
 @Override
 public void onWrite(final PageRange[] pageRanges,
               final ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
               final CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
               final WriteResultCallback callback) {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < totalpages; i++) {
   if (pageInRange(pageRanges, i))
      {
        PageInfo newPage = new PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, 
                          pageHeight, i).create();
        
        PdfDocument.Page page = myPdfDocument.startPage(newPage);

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
      callback.onWriteCancelled();
      myPdfDocument.close();
      myPdfDocument = null;
      return;
        }
        drawPage(page, i);
        myPdfDocument.finishPage(page);  
   }
  }
      
  try {
   myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(
               destination.getFileDescriptor()));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
   return;
  } finally {
   myPdfDocument.close();
   myPdfDocument = null;
  }

  callback.onWriteFinished(pageRanges);
 }
 
 private boolean pageInRange(PageRange[] pageRanges, int page)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i<pageRanges.length; i++)
  {
   if ((page >= pageRanges[i].getStart()) && 
                                      (page <= pageRanges[i].getEnd()))
    return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
 

 private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page, 
            int pagenumber) {
  Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

  pagenumber++; // Make sure page numbers start at 1

  int titleBaseLine = 72;
  int leftMargin = 54;

  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  paint.setTextSize(40);
  canvas.drawText(
    "Test Print Document Page " + pagenumber,
                                 leftMargin,
                                 titleBaseLine, 
                                 paint);

  paint.setTextSize(14);
  canvas.drawText("This is some test content to verify that custom document printing works", leftMargin, titleBaseLine + 35, paint);

  if (pagenumber % 2 == 0)
   paint.setColor(Color.RED);
  else
   paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

  PageInfo pageInfo = page.getInfo();


  canvas.drawCircle(pageInfo.getPageWidth()/2,
    pageInfo.getPageHeight()/2, 
    150, 
    paint); 
 }


}
```

Content of error logcat

```
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806): Process: com.example.essaib, PID: 806
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3835)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4450)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18600)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3830)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  ... 11 more
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at android.print.PrintManager.print(PrintManager.java:387)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at com.example.essaib.SQLiteExampleActivity.printDocument(SQLiteExampleActivity.java:138)
10-27 16:37:43.810: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: It's a `NullPointerException` -- find out what's null and make sure it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, problem came from a non-compatible hardware. 
Hard to trace, but finally found it.